# Smooth Streaming Playback doesn't work without Audio Stream

Tags: audio, streaming, playback, smoothing, encoder

I am having problems playing a smooth stream with the Antrica ANT-32000 encoder, when I record the ISM I get no data in the audio and if I remove it. I am acquiring the stream using RTSP. Is it a known problem that the video isn't able to play if there is a bad audio stream? 
This is the manifest I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <SmoothStreamingMedia MajorVersion="2" MinorVersion="1" Duration="560592442">
- <StreamIndex Type="video" Url="QualityLevels({bitrate})/Fragments(video={start time})" Name="video" Chunks="8" QualityLevels="1">
  <QualityLevel Index="0" Bitrate="500000" MaxWidth="720" MaxHeight="480" FourCC="AVC1" CodecPrivateData="000000016742a01fe7281687b60220000177600057e41c00000301ab3f00000d59f87fffc600000300d59f800006acfc3fffe0400000000168de3c80" /> 
- <c d="20019673">
  <f i="0" s="432020" /> 
  </c>
  </StreamIndex>
- <StreamIndex Type="audio" Name="audio" Url="QualityLevels({bitrate})/Fragments(audio={start time})" Language="enn" QualityLevels="1">
  <QualityLevel Index="0" AudioTag="255" BitsPerSample="16" PacketSize="2" CodecPrivateData="" /> 
  </StreamIndex>
  </SmoothStreamingMedia>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you set AUDIO to 1 in the Antrica settings page. Also, in your url make sure you link to it using: `camera_ip:554/video1+audio1`.